# What's the difference between declaring a final static variable on Superclass doing so on the extendedClass?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to create Objects. My code is something akin to:

```
public abstract class Fruit {
private static final Colour DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR = red; //let's pretend this is possible

 public static Fruit newInstance(char type){
   Colour myColour = DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR;

         switch(type){
            case ('a'): return new Apple(myColour);
 //and onward, until default, etc.
```

then I have

```
 public class Apple extends Fruit {
  private final Colour c;

  public Apple(Colour c){
   this.c = c;
  }
}
```

Now, I established that `DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR` is red, and then use it to create a new Apple. This works just fine. Plus if I want to have it be another colour, I can just make `myColour` become `yellow` if I want to, while still being able to call for a default value easily.

However, what the difference between delcaring `DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR` in  `class Fruit` and doing so directly on `class Apple`, something akin to:

```
 public class Apple extends Fruit {
  private final Colour c;
  private static final Colour DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR = red;

   public Apple(Colour c){
    this.c = c;
  }
   public Apple Apple(){
    return new Apple(DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR);
   }
}
```

In the latter, am I essentially creating several objects , thus creating the same `DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR` variable as many times as I create Apples, or since it's static it's the same variable being applied to all Objects Apple? What exactly is the difference/best way to go about it ?

Comment: Highly recommend reading up on what `static` and `private` do

Comment: Yup. I felt stupid. After spending the whole week thinking object oriented I pretty much started doubting myself on what exactly some stuff did, including how static works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not the best idea for your `Fruit` class to know details about child class implementations. Image the you have dozens of `Fruit`s, each with some default parameters. In this case you have to hold all of these constants inside of the `Fruit` class. Moreover, I don't think that you need this constant at all. The default constructor will do the job.

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {
  private final Colour c;

  public Apple(Colour c) {
      this.c = c;
  }

  public Apple() {
      this(Colour.RED);
  }
}
```

And the factory method will look like this:

```
public static Fruit newInstance(char type){
    ....
    switch(type){
        case ('a'): return new Apple();
}
```

You encapsulate the default behavior to the `Fruit` implementation, and you still have a way to change this behavior using the main constructor.

What about your factory method, I wouldn't have it inside the `Fruit` class for the same reason: you parent class depends on child classes and it breaks the Open/closed principle. My suggestion is to create a `FruitFactory` that will deal with instantiating of your fruits.

Answer (score -1):

in this code you posted the visibility of those values are limited to the class only

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Apple.DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR ); //not compiling
    System.out.println(Fruit.DEFAULT_APPLE_COLOUR );

}
```

on the other hand, the color of the apple is a thing that belongs more to the apple and not the fruit class, in the future many fruits will appear in the application, so you dont need to modify the super class to adapt it for every new child class... showing from the arch point of view, the super class should never ever be aware of specific child classes, i mean fruit class should never be aware of the existence or not of an apple class...